# It is possible to refresh the data in spreadsheet by selecting any cell in spread sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am created real time data add-in using spread sheet it works fine all functionalities except refresh of the data. once data is binding to spread sheet cells i cannot refresh that data using refresh button.it is possible to refresh the data spread sheet.
[image]

how to refresh that data using refresh button

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question but you could try calling the `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` method at the end of your function?

Comment: i am also trying that one but its not working for me

Comment: What is the data? Are they formulas? Can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: data is table view format data.yes i am using formula is (=getgoogledata(name))   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1svATo-JNJw3Oe8tTpRqzm_E2b2j7gtwG-GzatZwPWvk/edit#gid=563585286   i am geeting data from my server

Comment: Data is table view format data.Yes i am using formulas that formula is(=getgoogledata(name).

Comment: i am using below code                                                                      for(var i=0;i<gsitems.length;i++)
   {
     Browser.msgBox(gsitems[i]);
     //SetInfoViewWithName(gsitems[i])
    cell.setFormula('=getgoogledata("'+ gsitems[i]+'")');
   }

Answer (score 0):

Since you want real-time data updates, try using Firebase, Google's real-time database. There's a [Read and Write data in Firebase from Apps Script](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script) tutorial. See if it suits your purpose. You may not be needing that refresh button then.

If none of this resolves your issue, then the feature you're looking for may not be supported yet.